# Bagging and max_feature in Random Forest

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

I do not understand the part that "smaller max_feature reduce overfitting in Random forest" ?
Also, what does it mean by bagging in Random Forest ?

Comment: This is more of a question for data-analysis, not really a coding problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do my best to explain to you. You seem like you're new to Machine Learning algorithms. I'm sure you know what overfitting is! So let me explain why this happens very easily with Random Forest. Copying this users answer: https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/30903/kyle-hale,

Once there was a girl named Mel. And every day Mel played with a different friend, and every day she played it was a sunny, wonderful day.

Mel played with

Jordan on Monday,

Lily on Tuesday,

Mimi on Wednesday,

Olive on Thursday .. and then

on Friday Mel played with Brianna, and it rained. It was a terrible thunderstorm!

More days, more friends!

Mel played with Kwan on Saturday,

Grayson on Sunday,

Asa on Monday... and then

on Tuesday Mel played with Brooke and it rained again, even worse than before!

Now Mel's mom made a time-table for Mel deciding who she should play with and when, so that night during dinner she starts telling Mel all about the new time-table she has lined up. "Luis on Wednesday, Ryan on Thursday, Jemini on Friday, Bianca on Saturday -"

Mel frowned.

Mel's mom asked, "What's the matter, Mel, don't you like Bianca?"

Mel replied, "Oh, sure, she's great, but every time I play with a friend whose name starts with B, it rains!"

What's wrong with Mel's answer?

Well, it might not rain on Saturday.

Well, I don't know, I mean, Brianna came and it rained, Brooke came and it rained...

Yeah, I know, but rain doesn't depend on your friends.

This is exactly what happens with Random Forest. When you add too many features which is represented by "max_feature" variable, you will try very hard to find patterns where they don't exist and end up being too exact with the existing data that you overfit. When you're using decision trees (Random Forest) you will always get the best fit, since you're breaking the tree into branches and each branch will literally take in every feature and every possibility (if that makes sense).

For what is Bagging in Random Forest? You must first understand how the Random Forest traverses down the tree (it makes many trees and takes some kind of average) and decides which feature to consider important and so this requires you to FULLY UNDERSTAND how it works. You should probably YouTube it.